# SetAttribute is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

This variable represents a input where the type=text

```
var x=document.getElementById('fiber-count');
```

I have this function:

```
x.onkeyup=function(){
var u=x.value;
var v=parseInt(u);
var n=isNaN(u);

if(n){
    this.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Invalid Character');

    setTimeout(function(){this.setAttribute('placeholder','');},3000);
    x.value="";

}
if(v<1){
    this.setAttribute('placeholder', "Min. value is 1");
    setTimeout(function(){this.setAttribute('placeholder','');},3000);
    x.value='';
}
if(v>864){
    this.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Max. value is 864');
    setTimeout(function(){this.setAttribute('placeholder','');},3000);
    x.value='';
};

if(v<=12&&v>=1){
    tr.removeAttribute('disabled');
}else{
    tr.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}

if(v==2){
    swr.removeAttribute('disabled');
}else{
    swr.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}
if(v!==2){
    document.getElementById('cable_type').selectedIndex='0';
    f_c.classList.remove('hidden');
    var top=document.getElementsByName('subunit');
    for(i=0; i<top.length; i++){
        top[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
    }

}
if(v==1){
    document.getElementById('radio_option_1').checked=true;
}
if(v==12&&bast[0].checked){
    document.getElementById('diameter').selectedIndex='3';
}
if(v>=12||v==8){
    document.getElementById('sub_four').removeAttribute('disabled');
    console.log('ribbon ought to be enabled');
}else{
    //document.getElementById('sub_four').setAttribute('disabled',    'disabled');
    document.getElementById('sub_four').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    console.log('ribbon disabled')
}
};
```

The problem is this: none of the setAttribute() methods are working in IE. I can't figure out why. I am using the setAttribute() method to set the placeholder and disabled attributes of several elements. The problem is this: I get this error message when I type 12 into the input.

[image: My error message]

I've tried to use the property notation

```
element.disabled=true;
```

but that doesn't seem to work, as if setting it via the property notation doesn't immediately update it or something. I'd post a fiddle, but that wouldn't work because this bug only occurs in IE, so JSFiddle wouldn't replicate it.

Is there any way that I can correct this? A polyfill maybe? Please no Jquery.

Comment: `this` is function scoped. Try  `var that = this` outside the timeout, and use `that` inside.

Comment: i'll give it a try. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is `setTimeout` runs in other context, then the keyword `this` is not referencing to `x`, that means is not the DOM element, but the global object (`window`).

Instead using `this` keyword, use the variable `x` to reference your DOM element, e.g:

`x.setAttribute` instead of `this.setAttribute`

Here you can test with this mockup:

```
var x = { 
    onkeyup: function() {
        console.log("this = x:", this === x);
        console.log("this.value:", this.value); //x.value = "hello"
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("-setTimeout-");
            console.log("this:", this); //window, not 'x' as expected
            console.log("this.value:", this.value); //undefined
        }, 3000);
    },
    value: 'hello'
};

console.log(x.value);
x.onkeyup();
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` in the `setTimeout` handler is referring to `window` and not `<div id="fiber-count">`. You need to store the `this` and use it inside the `setTimeout`.

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function(){self.setAttribute('placeholder','');},3000);
```

Or,

```
setTimeout(function(){this.setAttribute('placeholder','');}.bind(this),3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the false alarm, all. I found the problem: I had another variable named x, and since the other variable x was a local variable, the references of X inside the onchange function referred to the other, global x variable. I simply changed the local x to a global variable k, and all references to it as well. That solved the problem.